# Building PyV8 (a C++/Python project) from source in Windows

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

How do you get started running (and debugging) a C++/Python combined project?

So far I've started with the basics:

1. Checking out the project from source (http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/source/checkout)
2. Copying a helloworld.py example into the directory with PyV8, so it can import PyV8.

This doesn't work, of course:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 4, in <module>
    import PyV8
  File "C:\Users\Default User\Documents\pyv8-read-only\PyV8.py", line 32, in
<module>
    import _PyV8
ImportError: No module named _PyV8
```

The next step is *probably* to compile the cpp files and somehow make them available to Python as a library, but I'm not sure how to do that from the command line. There appears to be a VS project but I don't have Visual Studio.

(It would be **way more awesome** if anyone could also figure out how to debug both the C++ and Python parts in Eclipse)

Help! Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need a C++ compiler and some other stuff. See [HowToBuild - pyv8 - How to build the module from source](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/wiki/HowToBuild) for instructions. Looks like gcc or VS 10 would work.

Comment: gcc would be a little awkward on Windows (might need to Cygwin/MinGW it). Is there a version of VS10 I can use without buying the IDE?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express).

Comment: The only question being whether Express will do what I need it do. Thanks!

Comment: You may encounter problems debugging because the Python interpreter is built with VS2008 and is a non-debug build, which I understand can cause runtime library [conflicts](http://bugs.python.org/issue13210) if the extension is built differently.